# RoR Application - 'countdown' to a fixed DateTime from DateTime.now

Tags: ruby, datetime, timezone

Edit: More informative

I'm working on an application that lists sporting fixtures, what I'm struggling with is having a 'countdown' until the fixture begins. At the moment I'm using the following Ruby code:

```
var = (question.fixture_date - DateTime.now).to_i 

t = var
mm, ss = t.divmod(60)            #=> [4515, 21]
hh, mm = mm.divmod(60)           #=> [75, 15]
dd, hh = hh.divmod(24)           #=> [3, 3]

report = "%d days, %d hours, %d minutes, %d seconds" % [dd, hh, mm, ss]
```

I can save the `question` to the database and save a fixture date as a `datetime` column using the following code:

```
<%= f.label :question_text %>
<br>
<%= f.text_area :question_text %>
<br><br>
<%= f.label :category %>
<br>
<%= f.text_field :category %>
<br><br>
<%= f.label :fixture_date %>
<br>
<%= f.datetime_select :fixture_date %>
<br><br>
<%= f.submit %>
```

When I call `fixture_date` to the view it is in the UTC time zone, I would like to be local time (England, UK) so that my report is correct. How would I go about fixing the code or the form? Ultimately I would like to show all of my fixtures (questions) and not show them if it is 2 hours after the `fixture_date`.

Comment: Now, 17:00:00 UTC is over two hours from now. The current time is 2016-04-30T14:43:00 UTC. Perhaps you're confused about what UTC means? (Hint: the time zone in England is currently observing UTC+1.)

Comment: Ah. Yeah I think I am getting confused, should've mentioned that yeah I'm in England, UK :P So should I be using a different method for the functionality I need?

Comment: Well we don't know how you've specified `fixture_date`, but it sounds like you want 2016-04-30 17:00:00 in the Europe/London time zone, not 2016-04-30 17:00:00 UTC...

Comment: Sorry, still quite new to this. I'll try to specify what I'm doing: I'm using this for a RoR app and `fixture_date` is a `datetime` column in my `questions` MySQL database table - when I use `question.fixture_date` by default it is UTC, so yep you're right I want to have it relative to my timezone; GMT I guess. Do I have to specify the DateTime.now timezone?

Comment: Well, if `fixture_date` is in the database, then you should be asking yourself whether you *wanted* it to be 2016-04-30 17:00:00 UTC or 2016-04-30 16:00:00 UTC. In other words, it may not be your reporting part that's the problem so much as the original data.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense. So is this something I change when saving data to the database via my form code: `f.datetime_select :fixture_date` which I've currently got?

Comment: Yes - it sounds like you probably need to convert that from local time to UTC.